# Cannot invoke initializer for type CGFloat with an argument list of type 'String'

Tags: swift, bar-chart, jawbone

I am making a bar chart from JBChart. I would like to change the chartData to String. please help me do it.

here's the chartData code:
     var chartData =  [1, 2, 3]

Then I want to change it to a String from a UILabel from other view controller.

```
var chartData = [score1, score2, score3]
```

But I always get this error (Cannot invoke initializer for type CGFloat with an argument list of type 'String')in this code:

```
    public func barChartView(_ barChartView: JBBarChartView!, heightForBarViewAt index: UInt) -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat(chartData[Int(index)])
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is clearly saying that `CGFloat` doesn't have initializer that accept `String` as argument. You can use wrapped around like first convert `String` to `Float` and then convert `Float` to `CGFloat`.

```
public func barChartView(_ barChartView: JBBarChartView!, heightForBarViewAt index: UInt) -> CGFloat {

    if let value = Float(chartData[Int(index)]) {
        return CGFloat(value)
    }
    return 0
}
```

**Note:** Be sure that this `String` have number as value otherwise it will return `0` for `height`.

Comment: you are right, the string has no number value. It return to 0.

Comment: @VonRalphMarquez May be you are working with wrong method.

Comment: yeah. I am finding it out. Your code worked. Only that the String I put has no value. :(

Comment: @VonRalphMarquez Means your string array is empty?

Comment: I think so. How about a value in a UILabel in the same view controller? will that work?

Comment: @VonRalphMarquez Don't get you can you please explain bit more

Comment: So, I found out that that Strings (score1, score2, score3) are universal strings:         var score1 = String()
    var score2 = String()
    var score3 = String()        So, now, I have a UILabel that displays the values of those Strings (above). Now, Can I just use the UILabel text String in this barheight?

Comment: so these Strings (score 1, score 2 and score 3) are universal strings and were used to segue/pass data from other view controller that w're also from UILabel and Int.

Comment: the UILabel that I want to use as source of String values contains value from UILabel from other view controller.

Comment: @VonRalphMarquez Then you need to pass that information to your controller where you are showing chart

Comment: I already passed it. When I put the chartData = [scoreLabel.text] it receives errors again.

Comment: @VonRalphMarquez What error? If it is your current question one than do like my solution

Comment: Cannot use instance member 'scoreLabel' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available.

Comment: Its obvious because you not know which property initialized first so simply declare the `chartData` first `var chartData = [String]()` and then in viewDidLoad initialized it

Comment: I did it. But now, this code (if let value = Float(chartData[Int(index)]) {) receives this error: Thread 1: EXC BAD INSTRUCTION.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140157/discussion-between-nirav-d-and-von-ralph-marquez).